# Splitting string with repeating of for loop is not returing properly

Tags: android, split

This is  a basic question, but I am facing one issue. I have one ArrayList and one string. I want to split the string based on the values in the list. But its not working properly.

```
 for (int i=0;i<tagNameList.size();i++)
        {

            words=text.split(tagNameList.get(i));
            Log.e("tagname","tagName"+tagNameList.get(i)+"\n"+words.length);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            Log.e("New Words","New Words"+words[i]);
        }
```

This is my code. For example my arraylist tagNameList has values of (@aryan, @aryan , @Lord Jaganadham temple) and my string is "Hi @Aryan check API response @Aryan  upload code at @Lord Jaganadham temple).... But if i am looping the arraylist my output is "Hi @Aryan check API response @Aryan  upload code at "
But expected output is:

Hi

check API response

upload code at

Any please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are splitting `text` every iteration ,but using result of only  last iteration. The second for loop get the strings split by last element of  `tagNameList` only.

Comment: I didn't get you. I want to split based on my array values

Comment: Make word a array of strings and do `words[i]=text.split(tagNameList.get(i));`.

Comment: @Yamuna Did you try my answer?

Comment: put the Arraylist and String value both.

Comment: @Krish... yes that is working

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help,

```
for (int i=0;i<tagNameList .size();i++)
    {
        text = text.replaceAll(tagNameList.get(i), "#");            
    }
    words = text.split("#");
    for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
```